# Create irregular spatial point based radius from real data in R

Tags: r, grid, spatial

I want to create a spatial point  grid for specific area. Since I have a real point in all over the area I decide to design this grid based on radius from my data. For instance create a grid that radius from real data is about 5 kilometer.

for example I have a data frame like this:

```
df<-data.frame(lon = c(52.08249,52.09444,52.09731,52.09779,52.09875,52.09922,52.10114,52.10162,52.10305,52.10401),
               lat = c (36.62644,36.61794,36.61590,36.61556,36.61488,36.61454,36.61318,36.61284,36.61182,36.61114))
```

and the plot for data is below result:

[image]

finally I want to create point just for yellow circle like below image

[image]

Comment: Your sample data image does not make sense... there is no more than +/- 2000 meters bewteen the points, so a 5k buffer will not fit bewteen .. see: `df %>% sf::st_as_sf(coords =  c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% sf::st_distance()` I guess an approach could be drawing 10k buffers, and calculate the intersect of these as the center of the yellow circles.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right but this is just an example and if I get the script I will change the distance between point to actual values later. 
I wanted just to create grid that distance between point is a function of the distance from the original data.